# Joining two Dataframes under string.find() condition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
  
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col_name':['12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21','22','23']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col_name_aggr':['12|13|14', '10|21', '12|15|23'],
                    'color':['Blue', 'Red', 'Green']})
```

How can I merge those two dataframes such that the resulting data set contains all the Elements from df1 and an additional color column, whose value is 'Blue' when col_name is either 12, 13 or 14, 'Red' when col_name is 10 or 21, 'Green' when col_name is 12, 15 or 23 and 'None' otherwise?

From my understanding, when I try to join the dataframes using the merge() function I can only specify the column on which to merge them on.

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on='col_name', right_on='col_name_aggr', how="left")
```

Is there a way to specify the condition on which to merge them on?

In SQL I would do it like this:

```
SELECT
 df1.*,
 df2.color
FROM df1
left join df2 on CHARINDEX(df1.col_name,df2.col_name_aggr)<>0
```

Comment: What's your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split values by `|`, create `col_name` column and remove duplicates if need match for any value:

```
df =  (df2.assign(col_name = df2['col_name_aggr'].str.split('|'))
          .explode('col_name')
          .drop_duplicates(['col_name','color']))
print (df)
  col_name  color
0       12   Blue
0       13   Blue
0       14   Blue
1       10    Red
1       21    Red
2       12  Green
2       15  Green
2       23  Green

out = df1.merge(df, how='left')
print (out)
   col_name  color
0        12   Blue
1        12  Green
2        13   Blue
3        14   Blue
4        15  Green
5        16    NaN
6        17    NaN
7        18    NaN
8        19    NaN
9        20    NaN
10       21    Red
11       22    NaN
12       23  Green
```

Or if need merge by all values joined e.g. by `,`  use:

```
s =  (df2.assign(col_name_aggr = df2['col_name_aggr'].str.split('|'))
          .explode('col_name_aggr')
          .groupby('col_name_aggr')['color'].agg(', '.join)
          )
print (s)
col_name_aggr
10            Red
12    Blue, Green
13           Blue
14           Blue
15          Green
21            Red
23          Green
Name: color, dtype: object

out = df1.join(s.rename('colors'), how='left', on='col_name')
print (out)
   col_name       colors
0        12  Blue, Green
1        13         Blue
2        14         Blue
3        15        Green
4        16          NaN
5        17          NaN
6        18          NaN
7        19          NaN
8        20          NaN
9        21          Red
10       22          NaN
11       23        Green
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it transforming `df2` a bit from a "wide" format to a "long one". Something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col_name':['12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21','22','23']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col_name_aggr':['12|13|14', '10|21', '12|15|23'],
                    'color':['Blue', 'Red', 'Green']})

df1.merge(
    df2.set_index('color')['col_name_aggr'].str.split('|').apply(pd.Series).stack().reset_index().rename(columns={0: 'col_name'})[['col_name', 'color']]
)
Out[1]: 
  col_name  color
0       12   Blue
1       12  Green
2       13   Blue
3       14   Blue
4       15  Green
5       21    Red
6       23  Green
```

**Update:**

Actually it may be nicer with the `explode` method that @jezrael pointed out:

```
df1.merge(
    df2.set_index('color')['col_name_aggr'].str.split('|').explode().reset_index().rename(columns={'col_name_aggr': 'col_name'})
)

Out[2]: 
  col_name  color
0       12   Blue
1       12  Green
2       13   Blue
3       14   Blue
4       15  Green
5       21    Red
6       23  Green
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a map which checks for each entry in colname the corresponding matching positions in df2["color"]:

```
def contain(x):
    contained = df2["col_name_aggr"].str.contains(x)
    return ",".join([x for x in df2["color"].loc[contained]]) if contained.any() else np.nan

df1["color"] = df1["col_name"].map(contain)
```